Am I allowed to convert to Judaism
I am wishing to convert and be jewish. I have done alot of praying and research and feel like this could be the best choice for me. But I'm not sure how to go about it

Be aware: Orthodox Judaism will not recognize a Reform or Conservative conversion.

Consult a local rabbi. Be prepared to answer a lot of questions first, and, if accepted, be prepared to undergo extensive education. Good luck.
